# With boost::gil, how do I get a gray8s view of a gray8 unsigned image or view

Tags: boost-gil

Using boost::gil how do I create a view that applies to a gray8 image or view and provides a gray8s view?

What I'd expect:

- for these two cases I'd expect each pixel value in the view to be equal to its corresponding pixel value in the source image minus 128

  ```
  signed_gray8s_view_t some_gray8s_view = signed_view(some_gray8_image);
  signed_gray8sc_view_t some_gray8s_view = signed_view(some_gray8c_image);
  ```
- for these two cases I'd expect each pixel value in the view to be equal to its corresponding pixel value in the source image (ie, no effect, the identity mapping)

  ```
  signed_gray8s_view_t some_gray8s_view = signed_view(some_gray8s_image);
  signed_gray8sc_view_t some_gray8s_view = signed_view(some_gray8sc_image);
  ```